# OCaml how to manipulate tuples?

Tags: list, ocaml, tuples

Let's say I have a tuple:

```
let x = (1,3)
```

I want to add 1 to only the first value of the tuple. How would I do that?

Comment: As indicated in Andreas Rossberg's answer, you can only build a new pair, because the type of pairs is already defined as immutable. If you really wanted to update the second component of a value that would  be changed in-place, you would have had to define a type for such mutable pairs and specify the first component as mutable, e.g. with `type ('a, 'b) pair = { mutable a:'a ; b:'b}`. Then you can do `let x = {a=1;b=3}` and `x.a<-x.a+1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use pattern matching to deconstruct the tuple and then construct the updated one:

```
let (x1, x2) = x in (x1 + 1, x2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Patterm matching is a typical idiom. Another way would be with `fst` and `snd`:

```
# let x = (1,3);;
val x : int * int = (1, 3)
# let y = (fst x + 1, snd x);;
val y : int * int = (2, 3)
```